# counting letters in a sentence and displaying a * for each letter

Tags: c

I am having trouble with counting the number of letters in a string and displaying them in a graph like this

```
a: ***  
b: *  
c: **  
etc...
```

I have a code that displays how long the whole string is in each letter on the graph. Here is what i have so far.

```
int main(){
    char Str[]="TheQuickBrownFoxJumpedOverTheLazyDog";
    int j, occurrences[26], Letter=97, index=0;
    while(Letter>96, Letter<123){
        printf("%c: ", Letter);
        Letter++;
    for(j=0; j<=occurrences[index]; j++){
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

This is my output:

```
a: *************************************  
b: *************************************  
c: *************************************  
d: *************************************  
e: *************************************  
f: *************************************  
g: *************************************  
h: *************************************  
i: *************************************  
j: *************************************  
k: *************************************  
l: *************************************  
m: *************************************  
n: *************************************  
o: *************************************  
p: *************************************  
q: *************************************  
r: *************************************  
s: *************************************  
t: *************************************  
u: *************************************  
v: *************************************  
w: *************************************  
x: *************************************  
y: *************************************  
z: *************************************
```

What can i do to fix this? I'm pretty lost as our instructor failed to help me figure this out. I've also looked around the website a bit and can find codes that count the characters but i cant figure out how to get it to then print the asterisks.

Comment: What do you want to say by "counting the numbers" ?

Comment: Your while condition is wrong.

Comment: You declare `occurrences`, don't set it, and use it after ??? There is no logic in your code

Comment: Half the variables you set you don't reference, half the variables you reference you don't set.  Throw this all out, think about what you want your program to do, break it down into reasonable pieces, and then code them up.

Comment: @YaatSuka by counting the numbers i meant counting the letters in a string, when i try to set occurrences to anything it gives me an error what should i be doing with occurrences?

Comment: So you want to count letters in the string `Str[]` but you never use it ? Think about your code, what you want to do, complete your code to make it meaningful and then if you need help again, come back here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's an example, it does it for all ASCII chars. Try to figure out how to do it only for the range you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char* string = "TheQuickBrownFoxJumpedOverTheLazyDog";
  size_t len = strlen(string);
  size_t occurences[128] = {0};
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    ++occurences[string[i]];
  }

  for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 128; ++i) {
    printf("%c: ", i);
    for (size_t j = 0; j < occurences[i]; ++j) {
      printf("%c", '*');
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the while loop with a for loop that traverses the string till the end ('\0').

```
 for (char* ptr = Str; *ptr; ++ptr)
```

The array must be hold `26 * 2` elements if you need to consider case.
If not considering case `26` elements would suffice and you can ignore the `else if` condition below.

Initialize the array to 0.

```
int occurrences[26*2] = {0};
```

Get the index to be incremented from the string inside the `for` loop.

```
if (*ptr >= 'A' && *ptr <= 'Z') { index = *ptr - 'A'; }
else if (*ptr >= 'a' && *ptr <= 'z') { index = *ptr - 'a' + 26; }
```

Then you increment the `occurrences` array at the calculated index.

```
++occurrences[index];
```

While printing the `*`, remember that the occurrences array holds the alphabet positions like so -

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```